# How to create two different Menu in one page for different type of user in HTML using PHP and CSS

Tags: php, html, css

I am very new to php and HTML, I need to create a page after a user log-in to show a menu for a different type of user.
1st user = employer
2nd user = job seeker

***The menu for job seekers should display at least the following options:***

Menu

Edit Profile

Application History

Search Jobs

View Jobs by Category

View Jobs by Company

Log Out

***The menu for employers should display at least the following options:***

Menu

Edit Company Profile

Post a new Position

Edit/Delete a Posted Position

Review Applications for a position

Search Applicants

Log Out

I was able to fix my code and login with two different types of users.
The only problem now is that my second user - employer, won't show the css style that I have created. Everything is working fine in the jobseeker menu.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php
    session_start();
    if (!isset($_SESSION['usertype'])){
        Header('Location:login.php?msg=Hacker');
    }
?>

<html>
    <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <style>
    body{
        background-image:
        url('background.jpg');
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-attachment: fixed;
        background-size: cover;
        margin:0;
        font-family:Lucida Sans Unicode, Lucida Grande, sans-serif;
        }
    .topnav {
        background-color: #333;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    .topnav a{
        float: left;
        color: #c7e1db;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 18px 70px;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 17px;
    }
    .topnav a:hover{
        background-color: #ddd;
        color: #1d77dd;
    }
    .topnav a.active{
        background-color: #ec5e5e;
        color: white;
    }
    </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <center>
        <?php 
            if($_SESSION['usertype'] == 'JobSeeker') {
        ?>
        <div class="topnav">
        <a class="active" href="http://localhost/a2/menu.php">Menu</a>
        <a href="profile.php"> Profile</a>
        <a href="#appHist">History</a>
        <a href="#jobCat">View Jobs by Category</a>
        <a href="#jobCom">View Jobs by Company</a>
        <a href="logout.php"> Not <?php echo $_SESSION['username'] ?>?  Logout Here</a> 
        </div>
        <br>    
    <?php  } //for employer
        elseif($_SESSION['usertype'] == 'employer') { 
        ?>
        <a class="active" href="menu.php">Menu</a>
        <a href="#profile">Edit Profile</a>
        <a href="#appHist">Application History</a>
        <a href="#jobCat">View Jobs by Category</a>
        <a href="#jobCom">View Jobs by Company</a>
        <a href="logout.php"> Not <?php echo $_SESSION['username'] ?> ? Logout Here</a> 
        </div>
        <br>
        <br>
        <?php 
            echo 'Welcome ' . $_SESSION['username']; 
        ?>
        <?php } ?>
        </center>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work, there has some problem in taking sessions that's why it wasn't working. You can do one thing when registering you can take `usertype` in your database. Suppose I am registering as a job seeker, then you can take `usertype` as a `jobseeker` value otherwise the `usertype` value will be `employer`.

When a user logged in obviously you are taking a session for login with username and password.

So after login, you have username, Easily you can get that specific username's `usertype`.
Then you can do an if else condition.

Suppose when a user loggedin you have take that user's username session is

```
$admin = $_SESSION['username'];
```

then fetch the usertype of that `$admin`
The query should be like this

```
$fetch_usertype = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM 'ypor_user_table' WHERE 'username_column' = '$admin'"));
 $usertype = $fetch_usertype['user_type_column'];
```

Now you have `usertype`, so you can go for an if else condition.

```
<?php if ($usertype ==  'employer') {?>
     <ul>
            <li><a class="active" href="menu.php">Menu</a></li>
            <li><a href="#application.php">Edit Profile</a></li>
            <li><a href="#appHist">Application History</a></li>
            <li><a href="#jobCat">View Jobs by Category</a></li>
            <li><a href="#jobCom">View Jobs by Company</a></li>
            <li style="float:right"><a class="active" href="#user">
        <ul> <?php; } 
    elseif ($usertype == 'JobSeeker') { ?>
        <ul>
            <li><a class="active" href="#menu">Menu</a></li>
            <li><a href="#profile">Edit Profile</a></li>
            <li><a href="#appHist">Application History</a></li>
            <li><a href="#jobCat">View Jobs by Category</a></li>
            <li><a href="#jobCom">View Jobs by Company</a></li>       
        </ul> 
    <?php } ?>
```

Comment: I just added my authentication code to the above. would you be able to point out how to use the $fetch_usertype? currently, I was told to use $hash to create the password and also I use $_SESSION['usertype']='JobSeeker'; to get the user type